# test for html5 data equality among a set of elements without a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

When given a set of jQuery objects which all have the same `data` element, asking for the value of that data by with regards to `class` gives me only the first element.

```
<div class="Class" data-bool=false></div>
<div class="Class" data-bool=true></div>


var val = $(".Class").data("bool"); //false
```

without having to use `$.each()` and going through all of the elements, is there a way to test for whether or not all their data values are equal?

Comment: Without any kind of loop ? No.

Comment: But *why* are you trying to avoid a one line loop ?

Comment: @dystroy It comes out to more lines for me, and I was just seeing if it were possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible. In all the `$(".Class").length === $('.Class[data-bool=true]').length` tricks jQuery is actually looping through the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decided that you have an aversion to loops today... ahem. You could:

```
if($(".Class").length == $(".Class[data-bool=false]").length){
   // cool stuff here
}
```

Comment: This only works on the original "data-bool" attributes in the DOM, and not on those dynamically added or updated via jQuery.

Comment: I know Pointy :) I'm being a little facetious.

Comment: In what way is this answer facetious? It works. It's one line.

Comment: Sorry, thomas, didn't mean to be a jerk, but yes it "works", but it's not something you would really want to implement. As @Pointy pointys out, the nature of the data attribute is that it should be assessed on the fly as part of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ .data(), as values may pop on and off of the element at runtime. Doing it the way I have answered works for one specific way (pre-existing data attributes added to the DOM), but in reality, the code goes against the principle of data attributes. I hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thanks bro. I got pretty bruised up in this thread just asking how to save some space.

Comment: Hehe, no worries. Just roll with the punches. Good luck on your app!

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this in one line, you could try something like this:

```
$(".Class").length === $('.Class[data-bool=true]').length;
```

This method will get more and more complex as you add more possible values to the `data` attribute and won't account for updates through jQuery's `data()` method. It would be easier to write a simple loop.

Comment: This will work *if* the data attributes are really attributes in the original HTML. If the data values are added or changed dynamically, then this won't work because the selector only pays attention to what's really in the DOM.

Comment: But each selector you've posted implicitly loops through the DOM!

Comment: You have a typo, `$('Class[data-bool=true]').length;` should be `$('.Class[data-bool=true]').length;` (a `.` before `Class` is missing)

Comment: @Conexion The jQuery object doesn't loop, it's up to the implementation of method you call whether to do implicit looping. The `data()` method only returns the value of the first element in the jQuery collection object.

Comment: The jQuery object is an implicit loop because it implies that at some point, the DOM will be looped through looking for that selector. Whatever method you call on that object that actually loops would then be an explicit loop. :)

Comment: @Conexion I guess so... I took the question to mean is there a way to do this without the programmer writing an additional loop.

Comment: No worries, the question is absurd to begin with so I am being decidedly being strict with their wording. I voted your answer up.

Answer (score 2):

If you really hate writing loops, you can get it over with by creating a jQuery add-on:

```
$.fn.allData = function(key, value) {
  var result = true;
  this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).data(key) != value)
      return result = false;
  });
  return result;
};
```

Then:

```
var allTrue = $('.Class').allData('bool', true);
```

The companion "anyData" is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, the *real* answer to this is **no**. Otherwise you could do it with plain JavaScript and no [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) :). Sure, you can reduce it to one line in *your* code but that's something else.

Comment: As a reminder, jQuery *is* JavaScript. Anything you can do in jQuery you can do in JavaScript.

Comment: @Conexion Yes, of course. But when you're working with jQuery you might get the impression that you're using less code while in reality jQuery it's doing all of it in the back (in this case the looping) hence the ~90kb that it's minified version weights.